# Can I play ARK: Survival Evolved on my MacBook Air?

Tags: mac, games

I bought my 13″ MacBook Air a couple months ago. I usually check the compatibility with [Can You Run It](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/) before purchasing the game on Steam. In this case, I'm buying [Ark: Survival Evolved](http://www.survival-evolved.com). Unfortunately, that site doesn't support Mac.

Is there any other website where I can check game compatibility for Mac computers?

My system's specification:

- Software: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63)
- Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB
- Memory: 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- Processor: 1.7 GHz Intel Core i5

With these can I play any of these games on my system?

Comment: Absolutely 100% not, my GTX 970 can barrely run it medium

Answer (score 4):

No, according to http://www.survival-evolved.com/ark-guides/survival-evolved-system-requirements.html

> Mac OS X
>   MINIMUM:
>
> • OS: OSX 10.9 or Higher
>   • Processor: 2 GHz Equivalent CPU
>   • Memory: 4000 MB RAM
>   • Graphics: OpenGL 3 Compatible GPU with 1GB Video RAM
>   • Hard Drive: 20000 MB available space

Your machine is under-spec on CPU & GPU & OS requirement.

Comment: I'm upgrading my os version lately and the file size is HUGE so it will take some time to finish it since my download speed is between 250-300 kb/s

Comment: by the way, what's CPU and GPU?

Comment: Central Processing Unit & Graphics Processing Unit.

Comment: does my graphics suitable? if so, can i play the game if all other requirements are met except for the processor?

Comment: Minimum spec really is what is says - it's what you need to even attempt to run the app, at its lowest settings. It it nowhere near recommended spec, which is what you need to be able to run it well. Very likely your machine will get the app to load & run, though it will probably be horribly slow & likely crash every time the graphics is asked to do any hard work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so and I wouldn't suggest you do.

Games recently demand very high specs and MBA is not a device for gaming. Even if the game runs, you'll experience frame drops and other annoying things that will make gaming a torture. There is also a chance that it would kill the device.

If you're going to play on a laptop at least choose one with a dedicated GPU, not an integrated one.

Anyway, You can check how your device will perform on [Can You RUN It?](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/)

Comment: don't you know? Can You Run It does not support Mac.

Comment: I just knew from you. Sorry.

Comment: nvm it's ok i just like you when i 1st knew

Comment: Not really an answer as this is based on assumptions. We have 3 MacBook Airs inthe house and all 3 run Minecraft OK, so the blanket statement that "MBA is not a device for gaming" doesn't hold true - it all depends upon the system requirements and also on;es level of expectation - the recommended specs for a game are based upon a specific frame rate, video quality etc. Also, recent integrated GPUs are better than older discrete GPUs so again, context is key.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. There appear to be major bugs on the Mac version of ARK that are separate from performance anyways - even if you had a newer, beefier Mac. I'm running a 2017 MBP with highest specs, and the graphics are acceptable, but it crashes periodically for unknown reasons.